# Quartz scheduled job not firing - possible unhandled exception?

Tags: java, exception, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have a web application with scheduled jobs using the Quartz library. Recently I encountered cases where a job didn't seem like it was being fired. I did some reading and apparently *if the job throws an exception, the Quartz scheduler will attempt to execute the job again*. Is this true?

In any case, I did some troubleshooting based on the assumption that the above statement is true. So let's say I have the following code snippet:

```
try {
   method.invoke(object, params);
}
catch (ExceptionA ea) {
   ea.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ExceptionB eb) {
   eb.printStackTrace();
}
// and so on so forth, catching a bunch of specific Exceptions
```

The important point here to note is that **Exception itself is not being caught**.

So let's say the method being invoked throws an exception which is not handled.

```
public void methodBeingInvoked() throws UnhandledException {
```

What happens here?

Answer (score 5):

Any *Throwable* thrown from a Job will be caught by Quartz and wrapped in a JobExecutionException, and not refired.
See the source code for [JobRunShell#run](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.0.2/org/quartz/core/JobRunShell.java#JobRunShell.run%28%29)

There is some [documentation on the Quartz website](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/best-practices#throwing-exceptions) which contradicts this, but after looking at Quartz 1.8.x/2.0.x/2.1.x source code, the documentation is wrong for all versions.

> A Job's execute method should contain a try-catch block that handles
>   all possible exceptions.
>
> If a job throws an exception, Quartz will typically immediately
>   re-execute it (and it will likely throw the same exception again).
>   It's better if the job catches all exception it may encounter, handle
>   them, and reschedule itself, or other jobs. to work around the issue.